# Elastalert filter on log levels and send an email

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elastalert

I have some questions in elastalert which are really making me stuck. Your help is really needed as I am in the middle of an issue. My questions are below :

- Is there any way we can filter on the basis of log level or severity?
- Is there any way for each entry in elastic search I should be able to send an email ( as I'll be having a grok filter in logstash to push only error logs).

I have tried by following one by one, but nothing worked.

```
filter:
- term:
#      essage: "*INFO*"
#      query: "info"
#      host.name: "*IPADDRESS.us-east-2.compute.internal*"
```

None of the above is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kinda broad, so, I can only give some pointers but you probably want to run something like this:

```
# From rules/example_frequency.yaml
name: Immediate attention is necessary.
type: frequency
index: logstash-ming-ossec-syslog-new-*
num_events: 1
timeframe:
    minutes: 10

#- query:
#    query_string:
#       query: 'res:failed AND op:login  AND (NOT acct:root) AND (NOT acct:(unknown))'

#filter:
#- query:
#    query_string:
#      query: "system.log.severity: SEVERE

#or whatever makes sense with your data
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "alarm AND error AND (critical OR severe)"
      default_field: syslog_message


alert:
- "email"

email:
- "ming@log4analytics.com"
- "fgh@outlook.com"
smtp_host: "smtp.mailgun.org"
smtp_port: 25
smtp:ssl: true
from_addr: "ming@log4analytics.com"
smtp_auth_file: '/opt/elastalert/smtp_auth_file.yaml'
```

Inspired by https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/blob/master/example_rules/example_frequency.yaml

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. So this below line will automatically filter the log level error ? 
      query: "alarm AND error AND (critical OR severe)" and what is this alarm ?

Comment: I have tried following
filter:
- term:

message: "*INFO*", query: "info",host.name: "*ip-IPADDRESS.us-east-2.compute.internal*" nothing is working

Comment: The above sample filters every 10 minutes; however, you have to adjust all the values to your system and plugin a search query that represents the type of error you want to alert.